# FTP status code response don't work

Tags: windows-phone-7, ftp, response

Welcome!

I have a little problem with own application. This app can be connect(sith socket) an FTP server, and its work fine. But my problem is, if the user use bad usernam or password, the program won't receive the response statucode. Whats wrong?
I would like to use this statuscode some clause to examine(usernem or/and password etc.)
Code:

```
public static void ReadResponse()
    {
        result = ParseHostResponse();
        statusCode = int.Parse(result.Substring(0, 3));
        statusMessage = "";       
    }
```

The ParseHostResponse() method contains next:
Code:

```
public static string ParseHostResponse()
    {
        SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = socket.RemoteEndPoint;
        socketEventArg.SetBuffer(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);

        socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
            {
                statusMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Buffer, e.Offset, e.BytesTransferred);
                statusMessage = statusMessage.Trim('\0');
            }
            else
            {
                statusMessage = e.SocketError.ToString();
            }

        });

        socket.ReceiveAsync(socketEventArg);

        string[] msg = statusMessage.Split('\n');
        if (statusMessage.Length > 2)
        {
            statusMessage = msg[msg.Length - 2];
        }
        else
        {
            statusMessage = msg[0];
        }

        if (!statusMessage.Substring(3, 1).Equals(" "))
        {
            return ParseHostResponse();
        }

        return statusMessage;
    }
```

If I invite to the ReadResponse() method, the Visual Studio answer with this exception: NullReferenceException

in this code:
Code:

```
.
.
string[] msg = statusMessage.Split('\n');
.
```

What is the wrong? This code issue to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202858%28v=vs.92%29.aspx#BKMK_RECEIVING

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I can't help, but have to start with these side remarks:

- statusMessage.Trim('\0') does not work (try it)
- statusMessage.Split('\n') is inefficient as it involves extra allocations (guess why)

Now to the actual subject: I never used sockets on WP7, but from what I know about async operations it looks to me that you start async op (by calling ReceiveAsync) and use the result (statusMessage) before the answer arrives.

Think a bit about your design of the ParseHostResponse() method:

- Bad name: Indicates parsing of a response, while it actually performs communication
- Bad functionality: The method indicates sync patter, but internally uses async pattern. I don't know what to suggest here as every solution seems to be wrong. For example waiting for a response will make UI irresposible.

My main recommendation is that you get more information about async programming and then reprogramm your app accordingly.